# getIntent() is undefined for the type PieChartView

Tags: android, jfreechart

I'm using the `afreechart` library to display some charts in my app. The problem is the class extends DemoView class, and getIntent() is from Activity class. I have to pass some extras in the chart app to make chart treatement. What can i do? Any proposals please? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: What does the class DemoView extend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `View` you can cast `getContext()` to the `Activity` which contains your `View` and thus you can access anything from that `Activity`.

```
class MyActivity {
...

private MyView mMyView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
     mMyView = (MyView)findViewById(R.id.myid);
}

public int getImportantInt() { return 0; }

}

class MyView extends View {

....

private doSomethingWithImportantInt() {

    MyActivity parent = (MyActivity)getContext(); // I meant this line

    int myImportantInt = parent.getImportantInt();

....

}
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, i think that casting is impossible in that case, i have: Cannot cast from Context to DemoView DemoView is my class that extends View.